# Getting issue while sending request with curl

Tags: php, curl

i have a api when i try to send the request via curl i am getting this error

> Failed to connect to lasoon.co.in port 80: Connection timed out

```
$country_id = '101'; // 101 for india
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://lasoon.co.in/location/location_api.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ApiType=state&CountryId=".$country_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
print_r(curl_error($ch));
```

This is my curl request code. when i send request from localhost its working fine. but when i am testing this on server it giving me same error.

Comment: It works fine for me. Is the url reachable from your server?

Comment: its working for me as well but from localhost. but when i send request via this url http://scratchscheme.com/test_api.php i am getting this error.

Comment: I cannot reach your server. If you can get SSH console on the server, try reaching the API location from inside.

Comment: Sorry, yes i reached. So, your server is not getting to the API and says "Failed to connect to lasoon.co.in port 80: Connection timed out". It should be a network probem and your code is ok.

Comment: but its working on localhost. I am not getting the actual issue

Comment: Yes, it works for you, it works for me, but your server at http://scratchscheme.com/ cannot reach lasoon.co.in/location/location_api.php at port 80. So, it should be a network issue

Comment: It's not a network issue, it's a configuration issue.  Check the URL being requested from the live server.

Comment: As i mentioned above i have code on local and live server and i checked URL both are same.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the URL you are requesting on the live server is getting altered somehow vs. the one on localhost.  The best thing to do is to debug using the following:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
$result = curl_exec($handle);

rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";
```

This will print an audit trail for your request including the URL that your request is attempting to reach.  Inspect that information and you should be able to find the issue.  [The above code was pulled from here](https://alvinnguyen.github.io/webdev/2017/01/24/curl-debug/)

Comment: @SubhashShipu the answer is not intended a solution to your problem, you have not provided sufficient information for anyone to solve your issue.  The answer is intended to give you a way to get to the information needed to solve your problem.  The short answer is "It's likely that the URL you are requesting on the live server is getting altered somehow vs. the one on localhost" in other words the URL you are requesting from your live server is not valid.

Comment: i am sending request on same url but from localhost then its working fine

Comment: @SubhashShipu if you added the above code you should see a bunch of new text output with the request including the URL.  You need to do this on the live server to see the actual URL being requested on there.  I see you are using a print_r but that's not the same, add the debug code I promise you will see the issue once you do that.

Comment: I did not found any bug in code i have tried a many time even i am not getting any log about Verbose information

Comment: you have to echo the verbose information in the right place, you have to echo it in the same place as all of that other stuff printing on the page

Comment: everything which i am printing is on same place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170475/discussion-between-dan-and-subhash-shipu).